# Best way for allowing Fragment to handle onActivityResult instead of going back to the MainActivity for in app purchase

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, in-app-purchase

I have created a fragment within my android app to handle my in app purchase, however when onActivityResult is needed to be called through this process it goes back to the main activity to handle it but I want to keep it in the in app purchase fragment (I am new to implementing with fragments).

I have followed the following link to implement in app purchases: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

I have made sure that all classes have super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); in their onActivityResult as some threads have suggested, however this has fixed it.

Just an update... this is still an ongoing issue.

Cheers,
Jamie